# Capture webhooks of third party service with an API

Tags: .net, api

I'm building an API in .net that wil capture webhooks events of a third party service.

Lots of actions on the third party service  will trigger the webhooks.

```
    account.deactivated",
    "account.deleted",
    "company.added",
    "company.deleted",
    "company.updated",
    "contact.added",
    "contact.deleted",
    "contact.linkedToCompany",
    "contact.unlinkedFromCompany",
    "contact.updated",
    "creditNote.booked",
    "deal.created",
    "deal.deleted",
    "deal.lost",
    "deal.moved",
    "deal.updated",
    "deal.won",
    "invoice.booked",
    "invoice.deleted",
    "invoice.drafted",
    "invoice.paymentRegistered",
    "invoice.paymentRemoved",
    "invoice.sent",
    "invoice.updated",
    "milestone.created",
    "milestone.updated",
    "product.added",
    "project.created",
    "project.deleted",
    "project.updated",
    "timeTracking.added",
    "timeTracking.deleted",
    "timeTracking.updated",
    "user.deactivated"
```

My question is should I capture this all in 1 Controller.
This will reduce the amount of code. but certainly will make it lot more complex.
Checking wich object it is making a dynamic insert/update to the database & ...

Or should't I create for every object a different controller, so know which object I have to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you gave is a little sparse but from a very "far away"-point of view I would recommend using multiple controllers. In modern software engineering you should, as a rule of thumb, tend to reduce complexity wherever possible. This helps to fulfill non-functional requirements like:

- Testability - you can mock data for every controller and every webhook separately
- Maintainability - adding, bug fixing, removing functionality becomes easier per controller
- etc.

Try to generalize common tasks between controllers. Otherwise it is no shame to introduce *some* redundant code.